# Dark Background in NavigationDrawer in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a problem making a Navigation Drawer in my App:

In the Screenshot below you can see the darker area in the Navigation View...

Can anybody tell me how to remove this darker area?
The second issue: Why does the Margin-Top not work?
You see that the "Large Text" isn't shown correctly!

[image: The Margin-Top and the dark area don't work!]

Here's my code:

-main_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

-nav_header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/txvAccountname"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/txvAccountemail"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should include your layout. Also, you draw your toolbar on *top* and also I'm guessing you have a margin on the bottom of your LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anybody tell me how to remove this darker area?

Remove this line in the XML

```
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
```

Also, see if this looks any better. Not sure if you need the Toolbar, but it looks like you are using the AppCompatActivity.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Real content goes here -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/nav_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
      app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu"/>

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes, I'm using AppCombatActivity...
I think its recomended, isn't it?

Comment: I removed the v7.widget.Toolbar and now It works! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To change the background color on navigation drawer interactions, use this method:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
//or you can use Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"); too
```

Need xml layout code for the other question.

Comment: I added the xml layout...
Sorry I forgot it!

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to remove that semi transparent black fade that covers the content. Try @cricket_007's answer and if that does not work, add nav_header Design screenshot to your question, so that we can check if that gray line occurs because of the header background or drawer background

Comment: no the error occurs in the Nav-Drawer, nav_header is only a linearlayout with blue background and two TextViews